# cmake customization target_link_libraries prefix/suffix

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am trying to prepare CMakeLists.txt for closed properietary toolchain and curretly I am stuck in some problems. Build environment is linux so created Makefile have unix makefile style (e.g. library pre/suffixes).
Compiler and linker unfortunatelly have nonstandard syntax and some conventions is in unix some windows and some custom style.

I partially solved this problem by re-defining variable:
CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE and CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT

One of problem is linker expect to provide standard library name like: libc.lib libm.lib etc.
but when I use: target_link_libraries(my_target_name PRIVATE libc.lib libm.lib) finally created makefile caused call compiler with parameter -llibc.lib and it cause error.
I tried manipulate suffixes and prefixes by setting: CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX and CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX but I see no influence.

I've also tried to use call cmake with such define: -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../cmake/mytoolchain.cmake but as side effect I observed that some intrnal variables was reset to defaults (e.g. object file extension change from source.c.o to source.c.obj in case of c sources) and it's not acceptable for platform linker and cause linking error.

From my perspective looks like I have to create new custom configuration for platform I use but I have no idea how to start. I see that MSVC have different configuration than unix makefiles but which files determine it's behavior?

Comment: `Compiler and linker unfortunatelly have nonstandard syntax` So write configuration for that compiler. You may find all configuration for any compiler shipped with cmake, each compiler has it's own quirks. Pick a template and write it.  `but when I use` then what?

Comment: Usually you use `target_link_libraries(... libc libm)` without the extension. Also it would be pretty simple to simply distinguish the 2 options `if(WIN32) set(_LIB_PREFIX lib) set(_LIB_EXTENSION .lib) elseif(UNIX) set(_LIB_PREFIX lib) set(_LIB_EXTENSION .a) else() message(FATAL_ERROR "...") endif() foreach(_LIB IN ITEMS c m) target_link_libraries(my_target_name PRIVATE ${_LIB_PREFIX}${_LIB}${_LIB_EXTENSION}) endforeach()` ... Btw: Please [edit] the question and add the missing parts.